# I want to move the content from a subdomain to the root domain (readme.io requires me to set up a cname for their program)

Tags: subdomain

Readme.io requires me to use a cname to install their product (currently on http://docs.foxpass.com) but i want to move this all to http://foxpass.com/docs and still use readme.io.  Is this possible?  If so how do I do it?  The readme customer support was less than helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's very specific to readme.io. Try contacting their support team to get help with this issue.

Comment: I am having this problem with a whole bunch of programs like http://intercom.io is requiring me to do the same.  Readme's support is not sure how to do it which is why I am here.